# Why does the fibonacci series start with 0 and the lucas series with 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers, lucas-numbers

Why the difference? And when we're deriving these series from eigenvectors, what difference does the starting point make?

Please help. I'm very confused. I have a test tomorrow and need to know the answer to this question. There's literally nothing in my book and I couldn't find anything on the internet either.

Comment: You can start the Fibonacci sequence with either $0$ or $1$.  There are some small differences in the two developments, but it's largely a matter of taste and convenience.

Comment: What are the differences? What is the significance of the starting point in both fibonacci and lucas?

Comment: The answer is provided by Binet's formulas.

Comment: You can read about the relationship between the two sequences [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas_number#Relationship_to_Fibonacci_numbers).  Starting the Fibonacci sequence from $0$ produces the same sequence as starting from $1$, except for an extra leading term ($0,1,1,2,3,\ldots$ instead of $1,1,2,3,\ldots$).  The differences are therefore in $F_i$ becoming $F_{i+1}$.  The statements of the properties may change a bit, but the properties themselves don't change in any fundamental way.

Answer (score 1):

The difference equation
$$x_{n+2}-x_{n+1}-x_n=0\qquad(n\in{\mathbb Z})$$
has a two dimensional solution space ${\cal L}$ of functions $x:\>{\mathbb Z}\to{\mathbb R}$. The initial conditions $x_0=0$, $x_1=1$ determine a nontrivial solution $(F_k)_{k\in{\mathbb Z}}$ called the *Fibonacchi sequence*. In order to obtain a basis of ${\cal L}$ we need a second solution which is linearly independent of $(F_k)_{k\in{\mathbb Z}}$. Initial conditions of the form $x_0=0$, $x_1=c$ would just produce a constant multiple of $(F_k)_{k\in{\mathbb Z}}$. We therefore have to start with initial conditions enforcing $x_0\ne0$. It seems that for the Lucas sequence one chooses $x_0=2$, $x_1=1$.

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Vector_space

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one nice property of the Fibonacci numbers that depend on the indexing.  The Fibonacci numbers form a "divisibility sequence" - that is, if $m | n$ then $F_m | F_n$.  (If $m = 3$, for example, this is the fact that if $n$ is divisible by 3 then $F_n$ is even.)  This doesn't hold if the Fibonacci sequence is indexed differently.

A lot of the relationships between Lucas and Fibonacci numbers, in turn, seem to be most cleanly expressed if the Lucas numbers are indexed as they are, for example $L_n^2 = 5 F_n^2 + 4 (-1)^n$.

If you're concerned about deriving these from the eigenvalues, though, I don't think any of this matters.